# Move jQueryUI Dialog widget element into another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

By default, jQueryUI Dialog will automatically append a ***widget element*** and a ***widget overlay element*** (if using `modal:true`) into the `<body>` tag.

My question is: can we set jQueryUI dialog to append its widget element and overlay widget into another element instead of the `<body>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in option to do this, but I've had success moving around elements when the dialog is opened:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).dialog("widget").appendTo("#content");
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").appendTo("#content");
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peMGg/

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you'd have to modify the jqueryUI.js file to change the element to append to.

Or you could modify your document.ready function to move those widgets